# How do you create a workload report in JIRA for an organiztaion that has multiple project portfolios?

Tags: jira, confluence

How do you create a workload report across projects in JIRA? The fields I want to include are 1) First Name, 2) Project Name, 3) Points the user has been allocated, and 4) Points the user completed in each sprint in a tabular format.

My organization has multiple project portfolios. A core team member, such as a developer, can be assigned to multiple projects. I want to create a workload report to get an idea of which developer is working on which project and how many story points he completed for each project during each sprint.